# Displaying a Table of strings on HTML5 webpage

Tags: html, web

I am trying to display a list of strings in a table on my HTML5 webpage. I am going to want to be able to add another row with a string in it off a button click and also delete a row from a button click. Is this possible to do in HTML5? Also, is there a way I can get and save a row value into a variable? Is there any good websites that are good for beginning HTML programmers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would have to answer your questions with a strong "yes, sort of". what you are trying to do CAN be done, BUT not with with HTML alone.

HTML stands for hyper text markup language and is used strictly to create the structure and content of the elements on a webpage.  ONLY using HTML the results are very plain.  markup relies heavily on two other types of languages that can be used in conjunction and defines them as elements in the form of scripts and styles.

here where i would start with a default table in html

```
    <table id="stringTable">
        <tr><th>Header One</th></tr>
        <tr><td>String One</td></tr>
        <tr><td>String Two</td></tr>
        <tr><td>String Three</td></tr>
        <tr><td> ... </td></tr>
        <tr><td>String N</td></tr>          
    </table>

    <button class="addNewRowButton">Add a New String </button>
```

the most prominent scripting language is JavaScript which is used for writing client side programmatic operations and functionality.  i am most familiar with using a popular javascript library known as jquery, to accomplish this task i would first include jquery in my page and then use functionality like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

          // some scripting goes here
          $('.addNewRowButton').click(function(){
                 $('#stringTable').append("<tr><td>A New String</td></tr>");
          });

     });
</script>
```

CSS - stands for cascading style sheets and can be written inline on elements, in blocks of style tags or included in a webpage externally.

```
<style>
     /* define your styles here */
</style>
```

to achieve your goals you will likely be using all three of these items together.  but specifically some form of java script to modify your web page once it has been loaded.  Java script is also the outlet you will be using to access and utilize variables.

[**i would recommend starting here: at code academy's intro to web fundamentals learning track**](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web) its a very good and very free beginners introduction to the subject matter and they have advanced classes to follow on all further html css and java scripting

i hope this has been a good primer and i would strongly encourage you to continue to read through Stack Overflow and grab a book (or five). [**also check out this great post about free programming books / resources.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/392926#392926)